# Best Way To Store Password & JWT on Mobile

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt

I have a Flutter and Angular application that previously used Firebase, but for various reasons I'm working on switching it over to my own RESTful API with ExpressJS. One topic I'm a little confused on is how I can manage my JWT and their renewal. Currently essentially my auth related endpoints for my API look like the following:

- /users/create-account -- Will create an account in the database and returns a JWT to be used in future requests
- /users/login -- Takes a password and email and will return a JWT to be used in future requests
- /users/renew -- Takes an existing valid JWT and returns a new JWT with a new expiry time

Now my plan is to set the expiry time for the JWT to `1hr`. So if the user is still working on my Angular or Flutter app, it will automatically call the  `users/renew` endpoint. However here is my question:

On web it is not a big deal if the user logs in and the next day comes back and is automatically logged out by the expiration of the token (mine as I said is 1hr). But on mobile, it is expected that the password be saved. My plan is to store the email and password on the app using [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) which is essentially a wrapper for Keychain on iOS and AES on Android. Is this a good practice and a viable model of authentication, as the password is never leaving the users' device? I have seen things such as refresh tokens, but I'm not certain on how that works, and if that would be a good fit for this situation. If refresh tokens are what I'm looking for, could someone point me to a practical example of them in use, or is my idea a valid model? Thanks!

Note: I would use third party sign in and OAuth 2.0, but currently because our app is on both Android and Apple, with Apple's various restrictions requiring Apple Sign In, I want them to be able to log in on Android and Web to, I'm staying out of third-party authentications for now.

Comment: Don't store the passwords anywhere.   You should only store the password hashes

Comment: If you look at the docs, here is Keychains for example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1 , it automatically encrypts the passwords

Comment: Thanks, just making sure the passwords we're never stored in plain-text

Comment: @johnny5 So is my way of exchanging tokens and such a good way?

Comment: "I have seen things such as refresh tokens, but I'm not certain on how that works, and if that would be a good fit for this situation. " Yes, it would be a good fit. Much better than storing a password. Look it up, the concept itself is fairly simple, implementations may vary.

Comment: @Riwen So I found a good tutorial on Refresh tokens and I think I can make it work. Do you think that having no expiration on refresh tokens and storing them bcrypt on my database and using the same method to store it as I mentioned in my question is a good practice?